# How does number swapping work with if statements?

Tags: java

I want to know exactly how these `if` statements are switching the numbers. I have never been asked to do non-descending order before so I took a little snip off the internet.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * Created by Nicholas on 10/26/2015.
 */
public class Main {

    final static Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Please enter three numbers.");
        System.out.println();

        System.out.print("Number 1: ");
        int num1 = userInput.nextInt();
        System.out.println();

        System.out.print("Number 2: ");
        int num2 = userInput.nextInt();
        System.out.println();

        System.out.print("Number 3: ");
        int num3 = userInput.nextInt();
        System.out.println();

        if (num1 > num2) {
            int temp = num1;
            num1 = num2;
            num2 = temp;
        }

        if (num2 > num3) {
            int temp = num2;
            num2 = num3;
            num3 = temp;
        }

        if (num1 > num2) {
            int temp = num1;
            num1 = num2;
            num2 = temp;
        }

        System.out.print("The numbers in non-descending order are, " + num1 + " " + num2 + " " + num3);
    }
}
```

Comment: Run code through a debugger and keep watch on the variables.

Answer (score 0):

The if statements switch the numbers by creating a temporary value to store the old number in before setting it to the new number, the other number is then set to the old, saved number

A more interesting way of switching numbers is with bitwise operators

```
num1 = num1 ^ num2;
num2 = num1 ^ num2;
num1 = num1 ^ num2;
```

This works from xoring the bits together, and because xor inverts itself when given the same value `((A xor B) xor B) == A`

Comment: lets say num1 = 20, num2 = 10, num3 = 30            Basically, since num 1 > num 2, the temp is created to store 20, then 20 is assigned to num2 because we want num1 to be the lower value of 10 to keep the numbers in non descending order.